# Proof for common denominator in addition over any field

Tags: abstract-algebra

What field axioms and then properties can I use to prove: $$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad + bc}{bd}$$ for any elements $a, b, c, d$ in a field, $b, d \neq 0$. I am trying to think more abstractly, however the only property that comes to my mind is that $\frac{a}{b}$ is just the solution to the equation $a = bx$ and $b = bx$ to use the multiplicative identity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "inverse" notation. We are interested in $ab^{-1}+cd^{-1}$. This is $(ab^{-1}+cd^{-1})(bd)(bd)^{-1}$. But a straightforward calculation shows that
$(ab^{-1}+cd^{-1})(bd)=ad+cb$, and we are finished.

If the *definition* of $\frac{a}{b}$ that you are using is that it is the solution of the equation $bx=a$, then as a preliminary step show that $x=ab^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

$a=bx$, $c=dy$, $ad+bc=(bx)d+b(dy)=bd(x+y)$ seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ In a field, if $\rm\,u\ne 0\,$ then $\rm\,u\,x = v\,$ has *unique* solution $\rm\,x = u^{-1} v.\,$ Hence, by uniqueness, we deduce that $\rm\:a/b + c/d\, = \,(ad+bc)/bd\:$ since both are solutions of $\rm\: bd\, x \,=\, ad+bc.$

**Remark** $\  $ [Quite frequently,](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3amath.stackexchange.com+dubuque+uniqueness+powerful++tools+equalities) uniqueness theorems provide powerful tools for proving equalities.